# Finding the cardinality of a particular set of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the set of $8×8$ symmetric positive definite matrices with trace $8$ and determinant $1.$ Find $\text{card}(S).$

Comment: Do you intend to ask for the cardinality of the ***set*** of symmetric, positive definite $8\times 8$ matrices? If not, what do you mean by "card"?

Comment: o yes "card" mean cardinality and the question is : Find the cardinality of the set of symmetric, positive definite 8×8 matrices with trace 8 and determinant 1.                                             nead  the answer with proper justification .thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cardinality is $1$.

The trace of a matrix is the sum of all eigenvalues and the determinant is the product of all eigenvalues. If $M\in S$, since $M$ is positive definite, by applying the A.M.-G.M. inequality on the eigenvalues, we see that all eigenvalues of $M$ are equal to $1$. Yet, being real symmetric, $M$ is diagonalisable. Therefore $M=I$. And it is easy to verify that $I\in S$. So, $S=\{I\}$.

Comment: well it is almost correct answer ,just need some proper argument.Here M is symmetric matrix , so all eigenvalues are real.

Comment: @jon I have already mentioned this: "*since $M$ is positive definite*, by applying the A.M.-G.M. inequality ...".